# how can I upload a gzipped json file to gcs bucket from bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I need to load bigquery data ( select with some filter) to gcs bucket with json format and then compress. Current airflow operator is exporting table from bq to gcs, Is there any way to push some select data with some filter from BQ to GCS?

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the `compression` parameter of [BigQueryToGCSOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bc026cf6961626dd01edfaf064562bfb1f2baf42/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs.py#L47):

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToGCSOperator
bigquery_to_gcs = BigQueryToGCSOperator(
    task_id="bigquery_to_gcs",
    source_project_dataset_table="DATASET_NAME.TABLE",
    destination_cloud_storage_uris=["gs://folder/your_file"],
    compression='gzip'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure SQL solution to this problem using [EXPORT DATA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement) statement in BigQuery. See the following example:

```
EXPORT DATA
OPTIONS (
    compression = GZIP, 
    format = JSON, 
    uri = 'gs://bucket/path/file_*'
) AS
-- query_statement
select 1 as x, 2 as y;
```

After downloading the file from GCS and extracting it from the arhive I get the following data:

```
{"x":"1","y":"2"}
```